# Propositional logic : simplification

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$(p\Rightarrow(q\Rightarrow r)) \Leftrightarrow ((p\land q)\Rightarrow r)$

I got $p\land(q\lor \sim r)\lor(\sim p \lor \sim q \lor r)$, but I don't what to do next..

I was asked to get rid of all the bi-conditional/implication operator

Comment: Use [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) twice on the LHS to get: $\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r$.

Comment: Use Material Implication + [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Negation_of_a_conjunction) on the RHS.

Comment: Nw we have $(¬p∨¬q∨r) \Leftrightarrow (¬p∨¬q∨r)$ that can be rewriten as $[(¬p∨¬q∨r) \to (¬p∨¬q∨r)] \land [(¬p∨¬q∨r) \to (¬p∨¬q∨r)]$.

Comment: Using [Idempotent law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) this in turn amounts to: $(¬p∨¬q∨r)→(¬p∨¬q∨r)$ that in turn can be rewritten as: $\lnot (¬p∨¬q∨r) \lor (¬p∨¬q∨r)$.

Comment: Do you know natural deduction?